# How to use ssl socket writte in php from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: php, sockets, google-chrome-extension, streaming

We are developing a Chrome Extension. The goal is to let the user select a file from the computer, stream that file to a server for processing and have it back to save it locally.

We did a PHP script that can open a socket to receive/send files. We use it to send files from other servers. It is currently working.

How can we achieve this funcionality of sending/receiving files *using the same PHP script* that we already have?

This is the script in PHP we used to test it:
'''
<?php

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://MY_URL", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp)                                                      
{   
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}

$jFileName = "sample.jpg";
$file=fopen($jFileName,'rb');   
$vars = array(
    'file' => '',
    'token' => "MY_TOKEN",
    'filename'=> "samplpe",
    'ext' => "jpg"
);
$l = fread($file,1);           
while(strlen($l) !== 0)        
    {
        $vars['file'] .= $l;   
        $l = fread($file,1024);
    }

$content = http_build_query($vars);
fwrite($fp, "POST "."/mcMrProper.php"." HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Host: "."MY_TARGET_HOST"."\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n"); 
fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
fwrite($fp, $content);
header('Content-type: text/plain');

while (!feof($fp))  
{
    $input = fgets($fp);     
    if($input == "Start\n")  
    {                        
        $input = '';         
        break;
    }
}

#Javi
#unlink($jFileName);    
unlink("sample_outut.jpg");            
$fout = fopen("sample_outut.jpg", 'x');
$output ='';                 
while (!feof($fp))           
    {
    $output .= fgets($fp);   
    }
fwrite($fout,$output,strlen($output)); 
sleep(5);

fclose($fp);                 
fclose($fout);               
chmod($jFileName, 0666);
```

'''

Comment: What specific issue are you having? I'd point out that from a browser generally you can only open certain kinds of connections to the outside world - specifically a HTTP request, or websocket, or SSE connection. Pretty sure you can't open a raw socket.

Comment: @ADyson, is possible to send the file using an HTTP request, and send the file back? Otherwise, the only option would be to implement websocket comm aside of the current socket. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, files can be sent via HTTP, that's very normal

Comment: Actually on closer inspection what your PHP script appears to be doing is opening a raw socket and then writing content to it to send a HTTP request. I don't know why you'd do that when there are tools like cURL and guzzle and PHP which can help you send HTTP requests in a much more structured way without relying on building all the content of the request by hand (which is much more likely to be error-prone). But anyway certainly a browser could send a HTTP request to the mcMrProper.php URL directly (assuming it's accessible from the browser's network location).

Comment: @ADyson, those are very good points. Regarding the way to send such HTTP request fron the browser extension, could you point me to an example that we can "use as inspiration"? Some pseudo-code would do the job

Comment: Well you'd likely do it via AJAX, for which there are billions of examples online already. The HTTP request in your PHP script is unconventional though - it seems to take the raw bytes of the file and pretend it's a normal plain-text request, rather than doing the uploading using the normal multipart/form-data format used in HTTP requests for file uploads. So bear that in mind when writing your JS code. Also as it's a browser extension, I believe you'll have some tasks relating to permissions to sort out when configuring the extension, although I'm not familiar with the specifics myself.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for that. I would like to have a look at the tools you mentioned. If I want to re-write this in a more "structured way", where should I start from for the server-side script? And for the wordpress plugin?

Comment: Which part is the wordpress plugin? I don't know much about wordpress anyway. And which server-side script are you referring to? Do you mean mcMrProper.php? There are lots of tutorials online which show you the normal way to receive file uploads using PHP. There's even a basic tutorial [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)